# Install HP LaserJet Professional M1132 MFP, connected to a Synology DiskStation

Tags: 14.04, printing, hp, hplip

I've got a HP LaserJet Professional M1132 MFP which is connected to a Synology DiskStation. I would like to install it to print from my Ubuntu 14.04. Ubuntu discovers the printer with DNS-SD and tries to connect via LPD.

But when I try to print something it complains, that it needs the HPLIP-Plugin installed, which I already did. I also tried using the hp-setup, but it didn't even found the printer.

I would appreciate any help or ideas!

Jonas

Comment: Please describe in detail what you already tried to get it up and running.

Comment: Have you tried connecting via Windows or MacOS?